# lean, mean & fast key/value database options to replace a file-based approach

Tags: database, qt, file-io, key-value

I'm tinkering with an IDE that uses individual files as a key/value store. There's one key per parsed file including headers and a single directory per session (which may hold several open projects), so a thousand or so entries is almost the minimum (the source of the IDE itself has 6900+ keys). These files are mmap'ed for speed, so the implementation is probably not really friendly on resources.

Qt is used here, so those keys are written (infrequently) and read (frequently) via `QFile`. The keys are simple index numbers (uints) read and written in random order, the values are byte arrays that go from a few hundred bytes to a few 10s of Kb.

I'm replacing that with simple class that hides a key/value database behind the relevant part of the QFile API. I'm not expecting to improve pure performance but rather make the code less file/resource hungry (that includes used disk space) while maintaining the current level of performance.

I currently have a working LMDB backend, LevelDB is about done (but not tested yet). Any others that I have to look at which don't come with a whole bunch of dependencies of their own? I saw a mention that KyotoCabinet is very good with random access, for instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [RocksDB](http://rocksdb.org/). It's a high-performance fork of [LevelDB](http://leveldb.org/), because LevelDB has had some problems with database corruption in the past. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/tree/master/examples) are some examples. It is fairly easy to integrate and I use it in my Qt projects.

> RocksDB is a high performance[1](http://leveldb.org/)[3](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/tree/master/examples)[4][5] embedded database for key-value data. It is a fork of LevelDB which was then optimized to exploit many central processing unit (CPU) cores, and make efficient use of fast storage, such as solid-state drives (SSD), for input/output (I/O) bound workloads. It is based on a log-structured merge-tree (LSM tree) data structure.

Comment: Looks interesting, esp. the possibility to store keys as arbitrary byte streams too (= the index uint directly without conversion to ascii), but ... made by FB, is that (still) a plus nowadays? :)

Comment: RJVB, it's community driven, so nothing to worry :-). Facebook had made some good stuff in the past, like HipHop/HHVM.